# Facing "throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Working into NodeJS with Typescript. So the major issue is I am trying to follow the One-To-Many Document structure using Mongoose. But as the question says, I face the issue:

```
throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Todo` is not a valid type at path `ref`
```

Here is the Model Code:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    firstname: {
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: "Enter Email ID"
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: "Enter Password"
    },
    todos: [
        {
            ref: 'Todo',
            _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        }
    ]
});

const todoSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,

    title: {
        type: String,
        required: "Enter a title"
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    content: {
        type: String
    }
})

export const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
export const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define a reference property in a schema, you just need to define its type and mention it references to which db model

the type should be an objectId

the schema should be something like this

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    firstname: {
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: "Enter Email ID"
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: "Enter Password"
    },
    todos: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, // here is the issue
            ref: 'Todo'
        }
    ]
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is just a more concise solution to Mohammed's solution.

`type` is the most important object key while defining your schema and it is missing for your todo field. You need to set `type` to ObjectId like this

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    todos: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Todo'
        }
    ]
});
```